# ssh public key authentication with PAM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, public-key, pam

My Ubuntu servers are using kerberos auth for **ssh with password failover using PAM**. *I'd like to add public key authentication as well*. As I read that doesn't really work.
Has anyone implemented this successfully?

Comment: Which steps did you try?  Please check this guide as well and respond  https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-18-04-setup-ssh-public-key-authentication/

Comment: ssh auth in my case is managed by pam/sssd

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by adding these lines to: sssd.conf

```
[domain/MY.DOMAIN.COM]
ldap_user_extra_attrs = sshPublicKey:sshPublicKey
ldap_user_ssh_public_key = sshPublicKey
```